# Continuity sketches in mail.app: PNG instead of TIFF?

Tags: ipad, mail.app, catalina, continuity

When inserting a sketch into Apple Mail from an ipad via the continuity feature, it seems that this is attached as a tiff file:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;
    filename=image.tiff
Content-Type: image/tiff;
    x-unix-mode=0666;
    name="image.tiff"
```

(from the source of the sent email).

Is there a way to request a different format? Many email clients do not support out of the box inline display of tiffs and this turns a fancy feature into an obscure message...

My current work flow is therefore to sketch something in Notes, open it on the computer, take a screenshot (PNG) and attach this, as PNG's can be viewed inline by many more mail applications (in my experience).

Is there a way to configure continuity to insert as a PNG directly and thus skip this step?

---

**Update:** Seems this issue has been around for a while: [This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/673342) is an (ancient) Thunderbird bug report reporting a similar issue (for pasted images in Apple Mail), but they dwell only on TIFF support for Thunderbird, not on getting Apple Mail to change the format...

Comment: What format was the sketched image?  I don't recall how the image of a note is saved.

Comment: @jmh the image was inserted as a TIFF. While screenshots are PNG by default, it seems continuity sketches default to TIFF..

Comment: you can make screenshots as jpegs if that will help.